# How to insert FCM to Room Database?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-room

i try to insert fcm data into  Room Database But it is not inserting,
this is the code  i try in my FirebaseMessagingService

```
class NotificationService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
 lateinit var db: NotificationDao
 override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    db = PrefDatabase.getInstance(applicationContext).NotificationDao() // getInstance is a companion object  fun in PrefDatabase

     if (remoteMessage.notification != null) {

         showNotification(remoteMessage)
     }
 private fun showNotification(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        ........
        .....
      //Saving 
     Thread {
         val notifi =Notifi(remoteMessage.notification.title, remoteMessage.notification.body)
         db.insertNotification(notifi)
     }.start()
 }
}


}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Do you face any Exception?

Comment: No, Notification work properly but it's not insert  into db

Comment: Then add insertion code

Comment: It is not inserting any data in db?

Comment: @Insert fun insertNotification(notification:Notifi)

Comment: Yes, it's not inserting any data from this notification service @Amit Tiwary

Comment: how you are verifying that notification is not inserted into db

Comment: There is a recyclerview that observe notifications (LiveData<List<Notifi>>)

Comment: Then the reason can be either your thread is not running or db primary key in not unique so duplicate data can't be inserted.

Comment: Primary key is auto increment